# SIOCGIFADDR: Cannot assign requested address Error in python

Tags: linux, python

I want to set IP address by using python's subprocess module.

I was trying to use it like this:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["ifconfig", "eth0", "50.7.192.226", "netmask", "255.255.255.248", "broadcast", "50.7.192.231"])
```

When I run this script in my CentOS server I get this error:

```
SIOCGIFADDR: Cannot assign requested address
SIOCSIFBROADCAST: Cannot assign requested address
SIOCSIFBRDADDR: Cannot assign requested address
```

I couldn't figure out where this error came from.

Answer (score 0):

You have the broadcast of a /23 if the network is 192.168.1.5

You may want to set broadcast of 192.168.1.255

Comment: Er didn't you just have 192.168.x.x address range in your question.  I'll come back when you are fully decided on the question! :-)

Comment: oh sorry i was modified! pls check it again ..thanks you!